# How to read a Word Doc in C# so that it displays as if it was opened in Notepad

Tags: c#, ms-word, streamreader, doc, notepad

I am trying to read a Word Doc in C#, and then display the result in a textbox. But I don't want to read just the text, but instead read the whole file, special characters included. I need it to exactly match the results shown when I open the same file in Notepad.

I've achieved the closest results by using StreamReader. Note that you have to [follow the instructions in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416957/how-can-i-read-any-file-into-a-string/14417140#14417140) in order to display any result. However, the result is still not 100% correct - some of the characters are interpreted (?) differently than if I opened the Doc directly in Notepad. Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: Might depend on the enconding of the text: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx
e.g.: Encoding.ASCII.GetString(text); using the example from your link.

Comment: Which characters are different?

Comment: For example, Notepad brings up the characters Unicode 255 (sort of a 'y' with dots above), 208 (looks like the Euro symbol), and 207 (?); while StreamReader shows Unicode 65533, which is a replacement character.

Comment: I think I got it - a big thank you to @ben-mcdougall. The code `byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)` and `text = Encoding.Default.GetString(data)` seems to have done the trick. The resulting text matches Notepad (almost) perfectly! (There is actually **more** text that Notepad doesn't seem to read, an extra 1800 characters at the end, mostly to signify that it is a "Microsoft Office Word 97-2003 Document".)

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might depend on the enconding of the text: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx e.g.: Encoding.ASCII.GetString(text); using the example from your link.

Just posting this as it seemed to have helped in the end :)