# Fetch data which is in between html tags

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a word document. When I upload that document, I need to fetch the name from that. I always have the name in the first row, the data in the word document is like,

```
Shanish K
shanish@gmail.com
.....
......
```

For this, I just converted the word file to html, and from that am trying to read the name. Once I converted the word file am getting the `style defenitions` also along with the actual content. I dunno how to get only the data which is there in the `first row`. Can anyone help me out here. Thanks in advance...

note:- I noticed something when I was debugging, that the actual contents are in between paragraph tags like `<p .....>Shanish</p> .....,` is is possible to fetch the data in between the first `<p></p>` ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? I imagine there are better ways of doing this than converting the Word doc to HTML.

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir can u please give some idea to do this?

Comment: I could if I knew *why* you're trying to do this. What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir am trying to do this for some resume uploading process. Once I upload the resume, instead of typin d name, am trying to read the name(which is always in the first row) and fill it automatically in my web form

Comment: If you have Office installed on the server you can use the interop assemblies. (Might be able to get a runtime installer for this. I'm not sure.) See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924056/is-there-a-way-to-read-a-word-document-line-by-line) question for more info.

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir am trying with interop only

Comment: Unless your resumes are in a very specific format  then this will not be trivial

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), [FizzlerEx](http://fizzlerex.codeplex.com/) or [CSQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery)

I would use FizzlerEx. Load the document and select the first matched p element.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;

var web = new HtmlWeb();
var document = web.Load("http://example.com/page.html")
var page = document.DocumentNode;

var name = page.QuerySelector("p:eq(0)");
```